# when is bunny hopping necessary?

Tags: svn, version

In [descriptions of the bunny hopping workaround](http://designbygravity.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/what-mother-never-told-you-about-svn-branching-and-merging/), it is mentioned that the approach of doing periodic merges from trunk into the same branch to later re-integrate the branch into trunk is problematic. I have experienced these issues myself (or so I thought). However, at the time I did not have time to dig deeper into them to truly understand the root causes.

Could you show a sequence of commits/merges from trunk on a single file on a [feature branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature) that causes a branch reintegration to fail? Is that even possible? What are the main causes of failure during re-integration when using the feature branch approach?

I want to make an informed decision regarding whether to use the bunny hopping mechanism or the single branch approach.

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is that this should only be necessary for SVN versions <= 1.4. See comment in referenced article http://designbygravity.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/what-mother-never-told-you-about-svn-branching-and-merging/#comment-174

Comment: "Solved" and still a mess. Just try it for yourself and with a couple of "branching/merging into the branch/merging back to trunk" cycles you would (maybe) have had enough. I also use `SVN` daily and am not happy with some aspects. I am hoever very happy with using `git` for other projects.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835488/subversion-merge-info-how-important-is-it